# Overflow:hidden is not for the divs of circle shape?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with the code below.
I want the reflection of the windmill and all to be embedded inside the circle shape, but i'm unable to do so.
Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

**Here is my html**

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

#Circle {
  background-color: #22304D;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #22304D, #5E7B9B);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Circle #cont {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px black;
}

#Circle #cont .top {
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 900px;
  border-top-right-radius: 900px;
}

.bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 390px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: blur(2px);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

.floor {
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 468px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 320px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.floor::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border-radius: 90% 100% 0 0;
}

.floor::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: content:"";
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  border-radius: 90% 100% 0 0;
  ;
  width: 347px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  margin-left: 122px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
}

.sky {}

.moon {
  background-color: white;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px white, 0 0 10px #1E2D49, 0 0 90px white;
}

.stars {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.stars {
  background: url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 0;
}

.mill {
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 50px;
  height: 140px;
  transform: perspective(12px) rotateX(3deg);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 330px;
}

.mill::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #FDC500;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.mill::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #FDC500;
  width: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.dome {
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 330px;
  margin-top: 125px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.fan {
  background-color: #37475E;
  /*37475E */
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 155px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  z-index: 7;
  animation-name: rotate_fan;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.fan_blade1,
.fan_blade2,
.fan_blade3,
.fan_blade4 {
  background-color: #37475E;
  width: 4px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: -28px;
  border-left: 1.5px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.fan_blade2 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.fan_blade3 {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.fan_blade4 {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  margin-top: -28px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.fan_blade1::before,
.fan_blade2::before,
.fan_blade3::before,
.fan_blade4::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 20px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-size: 10px 11px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, gray 2px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, gray 2px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to top, gray 1px, transparent 0px);
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes rotate_fan {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Circle">
  <div id="cont">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="dome"></div>
      <div class="fan">
        <div class="fan_blade1"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade2"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade3"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mill"></div>
      <div class="sky">
        <div class="stars"></div>
        <div class="moon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="floor">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="dome"></div>
      <div class="fan">
        <div class="fan_blade1"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade2"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade3"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mill"></div>
      <div class="sky">
        <div class="stars"></div>
        <div class="moon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="floor">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can clip the circle like this:

```css
  

body {
  background-color: white;
}

#Circle {
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0 round 250px);
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0 round 250px);
  
  background-color: #22304D;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #22304D, #5E7B9B);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Circle #cont {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px black;
}

#Circle #cont .top {
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 900px;
  border-top-right-radius: 900px;
}

.bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 390px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: blur(2px);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

.floor {
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 468px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 320px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.floor::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border-radius: 90% 100% 0 0;
}

.floor::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: content:"";
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  border-radius: 90% 100% 0 0;
  ;
  width: 347px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  margin-left: 122px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
}

.sky {}

.moon {
  background-color: white;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px white, 0 0 10px #1E2D49, 0 0 90px white;
}

.stars {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.stars {
  background: url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 0;
}

.mill {
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 50px;
  height: 140px;
  transform: perspective(12px) rotateX(3deg);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 330px;
}

.mill::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #FDC500;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.mill::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #FDC500;
  width: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.dome {
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 330px;
  margin-top: 125px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.fan {
  background-color: #37475E;
  /*37475E */
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 155px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  z-index: 7;
  animation-name: rotate_fan;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.fan_blade1,
.fan_blade2,
.fan_blade3,
.fan_blade4 {
  background-color: #37475E;
  width: 4px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: -28px;
  border-left: 1.5px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.fan_blade2 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.fan_blade3 {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.fan_blade4 {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  margin-top: -28px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.fan_blade1::before,
.fan_blade2::before,
.fan_blade3::before,
.fan_blade4::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 20px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-size: 10px 11px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, gray 2px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, gray 2px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to top, gray 1px, transparent 0px);
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes rotate_fan {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Circle">
  <div id="cont">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="dome"></div>
      <div class="fan">
        <div class="fan_blade1"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade2"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade3"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mill"></div>
      <div class="sky">
        <div class="stars"></div>
        <div class="moon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="floor">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="dome"></div>
      <div class="fan">
        <div class="fan_blade1"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade2"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade3"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mill"></div>
      <div class="sky">
        <div class="stars"></div>
        <div class="moon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="floor">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `position: relative; z-index: 1;` to `#Circle`

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

#Circle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #22304D;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #22304D, #5E7B9B);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Circle #cont {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px black;
}

#Circle #cont .top {
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 900px;
  border-top-right-radius: 900px;
}

.bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 390px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: blur(2px);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

.floor {
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 468px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 320px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.floor::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border-radius: 90% 100% 0 0;
}

.floor::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: content:"";
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  border-radius: 90% 100% 0 0;
  ;
  width: 347px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  margin-left: 122px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
}

.sky {}

.moon {
  background-color: white;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px white, 0 0 10px #1E2D49, 0 0 90px white;
}

.stars {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.stars {
  background: url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 0;
}

.mill {
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 50px;
  height: 140px;
  transform: perspective(12px) rotateX(3deg);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 330px;
}

.mill::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #FDC500;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.mill::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #FDC500;
  width: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.dome {
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 330px;
  margin-top: 125px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.fan {
  background-color: #37475E;
  /*37475E */
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 155px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  z-index: 7;
  animation-name: rotate_fan;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.fan_blade1,
.fan_blade2,
.fan_blade3,
.fan_blade4 {
  background-color: #37475E;
  width: 4px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: -28px;
  border-left: 1.5px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.fan_blade2 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.fan_blade3 {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.fan_blade4 {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  margin-top: -28px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.fan_blade1::before,
.fan_blade2::before,
.fan_blade3::before,
.fan_blade4::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 20px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-size: 10px 11px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, gray 2px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, gray 2px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to top, gray 1px, transparent 0px);
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes rotate_fan {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Circle">
  <div id="cont">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="dome"></div>
      <div class="fan">
        <div class="fan_blade1"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade2"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade3"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mill"></div>
      <div class="sky">
        <div class="stars"></div>
        <div class="moon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="floor">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="dome"></div>
      <div class="fan">
        <div class="fan_blade1"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade2"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade3"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mill"></div>
      <div class="sky">
        <div class="stars"></div>
        <div class="moon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="floor">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: why to set posotion relative?

Comment: z-index works only with elements that have positione set. it can be any position poperty (relative, absolute, fixed, ...) but it has to be declared on the element

Answer (score 0):

Like in similar questions ([Overflow hidden with border radius not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131314/overflow-hidden-with-border-radius-not-working-in-chrome)), it seems that setting

```
#Circle {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

increase `width` and `height` of `#circle` and  `#Circle #cont` so its display properly

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

#Circle {
  background-color: #22304D;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #22304D, #5E7B9B);
  width: 570px;
  height: 570px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index:-2px;
  position:absolute;
}

#Circle #cont {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 570px;
  height: 570px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px black;
}

#Circle #cont .top {
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 900px;
  border-top-right-radius: 900px;
}

.bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 390px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: blur(2px);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

.floor {
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 468px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 320px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.floor::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border-radius: 90% 100% 0 0;
}

.floor::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: content:"";
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  border-radius: 90% 100% 0 0;
  ;
  width: 347px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  margin-left: 122px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
}

.sky {}

.moon {
  background-color: white;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px white, 0 0 10px #1E2D49, 0 0 90px white;
}

.stars {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.stars {
  background: url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 0;
}

.mill {
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 50px;
  height: 140px;
  transform: perspective(12px) rotateX(3deg);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 330px;
}

.mill::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #FDC500;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.mill::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #FDC500;
  width: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.dome {
  background-color: #1E2D49;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 330px;
  margin-top: 125px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.fan {
  background-color: #37475E;
  /*37475E */
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 155px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  z-index: 7;
  animation-name: rotate_fan;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.fan_blade1,
.fan_blade2,
.fan_blade3,
.fan_blade4 {
  background-color: #37475E;
  width: 4px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: -28px;
  border-left: 1.5px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.fan_blade2 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.fan_blade3 {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.fan_blade4 {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  margin-top: -28px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.fan_blade1::before,
.fan_blade2::before,
.fan_blade3::before,
.fan_blade4::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 20px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-size: 10px 11px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, gray 2px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, gray 2px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to top, gray 1px, transparent 0px);
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes rotate_fan {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Circle">
  <div id="cont">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="dome"></div>
      <div class="fan">
        <div class="fan_blade1"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade2"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade3"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mill"></div>
      <div class="sky">
        <div class="stars"></div>
        <div class="moon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="floor">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="dome"></div>
      <div class="fan">
        <div class="fan_blade1"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade2"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade3"></div>
        <div class="fan_blade4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mill"></div>
      <div class="sky">
        <div class="stars"></div>
        <div class="moon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="floor">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```